# Aggregation & grouping with Kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on kafka streams and state stores. I have a logic below to aggregate group of message based on key.

```
 final Materialized<String, Sample, SessionStore<Bytes, byte[]>> abcStore =
            Materialized.<String, Sample, SessionStore<Bytes, 
 byte[]>>as("topicforchangelog").withCachingDisabled();


 KStream<String, Sample> abcStream = builder.stream("inprocess-topic");


 SessionWindowedKStream<String, Sample> windowedKStream =
            abcStream.groupByKey().windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(ofSeconds("36000")));


    windowedKStream
            .aggregate(
                    Aggregater::initialize,
                    Aggregater::merge,
                    Aggregater::merge,
                    abcStore)
            .toStream()
            .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key.key(), value))
            .filter((k, v) -> v != null )
            .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getId())
            .peek(abcClass::logOut)
            .to("outputtopic");
```

Based on the logic in the Aggregater class , i am able to merge the following messages as i expect.

```
 Message 1 : Key : A , value : {"id" : "abc" , "names" : []} 

 Message 2 : Key : A , value : {"id" : null , "names" : [{"name" : "x"}]}

 Message 3 : Key : A , value : {"id" : null , "names" : [{"name" : "xx"}]}
```

And the final message i am getting like below.

```
 {"id" : "abc" , "names" : [{"name" : "x"}, {"name" : "xx"}]}
```

**The** **first** **three** **messages** **are** **pushed** **to** **topic** **in** **the** **gap** **of** **5** **mins**. **But** **After** **some** **period** **of** **time** **(one** **day** **or** **more)** **,** **if** **i** **send** **a** **message** **having** **key**  **"A"** -

```
 Message 4 : Key : A , value : {"id" : null ,  "names" : [{"name" : "xxx"}}
```

My expection is to form a message like

```
{"id" : "abc" , "names" : [{"name" : "x"}, {"name" : "xx"},{"name" : "xxx"}]}
```

But it is not happenning. I am receiving output like {"id" : null ,  "names" : [{"name" : "xxx"}}

Aggregation is not happening with all the records present in the "inprocess-topic with "A" as key.

Is this because of

1. Can Session window is expired?
2. (or) Because of previous messages are already read by the consumer application and offset is committed?

**Can we acheive this scenario with SessionWindow concept?**

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess. Because you are using you a windowed aggregation, you may need to consider the following.

### Detailed behaviour of KGroupedTable/Streame

- Input records with null keys are ignored.
- When a record key is received for the first time, the initializer is called (and called before the adder and subtractor). Note that, in contrast to KGroupedStream, over time the initializer may be called more than once for a key as a result of having received input tombstone records for that key (see below).
- When the first non-null value is received for a key (e.g., INSERT), then only the adder is called.
- When subsequent non-null values are received for a key (e.g., UPDATE), then (1) the subtractor is called with the old value as stored in the table and (2) the adder is called with the new value of the input record that was just received. The order of execution for the subtractor and adder is not defined.
- When a tombstone record – i.e. a record with a null value – is received for a key (e.g., DELETE), then only the subtractor is called. Note that, whenever the subtractor returns a null value itself, then the corresponding key is removed from the resulting KTable. If that happens, any next input record for that key will trigger the initializer again.

Refer Row no:6 in the table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information.. is SessionWindows are expired and is this possible to take old messages with same key for aggregation?

Comment: Programmatically I haven't done this. But as per theory, - Session windows are used to aggregate key-based events into so-called sessions, the process of which is referred to as sessionization.
- Sessions represent a period of activity separated by a defined gap of inactivity (or “idleness”).
- Any events processed that fall within the inactivity gap of any existing sessions are merged into the existing sessions. If an event falls outside of the session gap, then a new session will be created.

Comment: ok..   As New SessionWindow will create after old session expires based on the retention period, I am assuming Windowing aggregation will not satisfy my scenario where - whenever message comes  irrespective of time , i need to aggregate with last aggregated message of that particular key... OR.. I need to consider all the available messages from topic with the key and perform aggregation.. Please correct if this is wrong.. is this scenario is possible with kafka streams? Can you help!

Comment: Yes. You need keep aggregating based on a key. And if we talk about stream, then you should have a compacted topic or changelog topic, so the latest value of a specific key will be retained always. You can refer the word count algorithm sample https://github.com/diegoicosta/kafka-confluent-examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java